# multiplication and division with decimals

Tags: c#

I´m new to C# and have now a Problem with mathematical stuff. Why can´t I mulitplicate or divide "simple" like this:

```
 decimal mLon1 = 0;
 decimal mLat1 = 0;
 decimal mFactor = 111021;
 decimal mRadius = 100;
 decimal mLat = 12.123;

 mLon1 = mLon - mRadius / Math.Abs(Math.Cos(((Math.PI / 180) * mLat)) * mFaktor);
 mLat1 = mLat - (mRadius / mFaktor);
```

Compiler Shows an error:

> *The Operator '*' can not be applied to operands of type 'double' and 'decimal'.*

Same with Operator '/' ...

How can I get my code workin?
Thx for any hint.

Comment: Didn't you also get a compile error in the line `decimal mLat = 12.123`? I believe you need to suffix it like this: `decimal mLat = 12.123M`

Comment: Break it down into small steps to identify which part is throwing the error. Without looking it up you may need some casts.

Comment: decimal is for financial and monetary calculations, these variables should probably be double.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try below code and you have spelling mistake near "mFaktor" which should be "mFactor"

```
decimal mLon1 = 0;
decimal mLat1 = 0;
decimal mFactor = 111021;
decimal mRadius = 100;
decimal mLat = (decimal)12.123;
decimal mLon = 0;
mLon1 = mLon - mRadius / (decimal)Math.Abs(Math.Cos(((Math.PI / 180) * (double)mLat)) * (double)mFactor);
mLat1 = mLat - (mRadius / mFactor);
```

Comment: Sorry, the spelling mistake is only in my Hand typed samlpe here. Your solution with the cast as double an decimal works. thx!

Answer (score 4):

C# is a **type-safe** language, what i meant by type safe is that the code allows the developer to be certain that a value or object will  be of a certain type so that he/she can use it in a specific way without fear of unexpected or undefined behavior.
C# only some implicit conversion of types like int to double

Change your code as shown below

```
decimal mLon1 = 0M;
decimal mLat1 = 0M;
decimal mFactor = 111021M;//mFactor is never used
decimal mRadius = 100M;
decimal mLat = 12.123M;

mLon1 = mLon - mRadius / Math.Abs(Convert.ToDecimal(Math.Cos((Math.PI / 180) * Convert.ToDouble(mLat))) * mFaktor);//mFaktor and mLon is not defined
mLat1 = mLat - (mRadius / mFaktor);
```

Here `Convert.ToDouble(mLat)` converts `mLat` to `double` since C# doesn't allow implicit conversion of `decimal` to `double`, why am I doing this? Well `Math.Cos` apparently accepts only `double`, so is the case of `Math.Abs`

Another workaround is that you could convert every declared variables as `double` and reduce the pain of explicit type conversions in between

```
double mLon1 = 0D;
double mLat1 = 0D;
double mFactor = 111021D;//mFactor is never used
double mRadius = 100D;
double mLat = 12.123D;

mLon1 = mLon - mRadius / Math.Abs(Math.Cos(((Math.PI / 180D) * mLat)) * mFaktor);//mFaktor and mLon is not defined
mLat1 = mLat - (mRadius / mFaktor);
```

Please see the below mentioned reference and what type is that you want to use in the present scenario that you are facing.

[image: Floating point reference]

Reference: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/1dhd7f2x.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use the decimal type for this usage. Use the double type and everything will be fine.

In your case, the math function returns a double precision floating point (64 bits) number and the decimal type is a 128 bits floating point non-native data type.

You can't directly multiply two numbers that don't have the same memory size.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your code doesn't even compile.

If you want to use `12.123` as a `decimal`, you need to use `m` or `M` suffix. If you don't use any suffix with your floating type, C# thinks it is a `double`.

From [`decimal` (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx)

> If you want a numeric real literal to be treated as decimal, use the
>   suffix m or M. Without the suffix m, the number is treated as a double
>   and generates a compiler error.

And [there are no implicit conversions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y5b434w4.aspx) between *floating-point types* (`float` and `double`) and the `decimal` type.

Since [`Math.PI`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.pi%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) field represents `double`, your `Math.PI / 180` will be `double`. Since `mLat` is `decimal` (you said it is a spelling mistake) you try to get `double * decimal` which is clearly you get these error. You try to same operation with `/` operator also.

From C# Spec [$7.7.1 Multiplication operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691372%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

```
float operator *(float x, float y);
double operator *(double x, double y);
decimal operator *(decimal x, decimal y);
```

And from C# Spec [$7.7.2 Division operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691373%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

```
float operator /(float x, float y);
double operator /(double x, double y);
decimal operator /(decimal x, decimal y);
```

As you can see from these documentations, there is no defined `double * decimal` or `double / decimal` operations.

Comment: OK, I understand the conversion matter now. But my main variables should be still `decimal`s because I´m working in this case with geo-Points within a database. I´ve read some Posts about the Problems with the behaviour based on base 10 representations (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165761/decimal-vs-double-which-one-should-i-use-and-when). Which type should I use in my case? I don´t need an accuracy of more than 10 Meters in my calculations...

Answer (score 0):

You could also use variables of type `double` instead of `decimal`.